# React Countup trigger start when state is true

Tags: reactjs

I would like to start the Counter when the related state value is true.

According to the document, the counter can be triggered with a button for example if the button is inside the Component. I would like to find a way how to start is from outside of the Component. I can't figure it out how to trigger the start.

```
<CountUp start={0} end={100}>
    {({ countUpRef, start }) => (
        <div>
            <span ref={countUpRef} />
            <button onClick={start}>Start</button>
        </div>
    )}
</CountUp>
```

Reference: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-countup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is said in the documentation

```
    <CountUp start={0} end={100} delay={0}>
      {({ countUpRef }) => (
        <div>
          <span ref={countUpRef} />
        </div>
      )}
    </CountUp>
```

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-countup#autostart-with-render-prop

EDIT: You can use the useCountUp hook

```
 const { countUp, start, pauseResume, reset, update } = useCountUp(...)
```

Then you can get the start function and trigger it from outside. Below a simplified example from the doc.

```
import { useCountUp } from 'react-countup';


const ExternalComponent = () => {
  const { countUp, start } = useCountUp({
    start: 0,
    end: 1234567,
  });

  useEffect(()=> start(), [])

  return (
    <div>
      <div>{countUp}</div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Here I trigger after the first render but you can easily put other condition on it.

Answer (score 1):

if you pass `redraw={true}` as a prop to `CountUp` component ,then it will rerendered after any state change (or after any render)